# Python: finding indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, find, vectorization

If I have a and b:

```
a=[[1,2,3],
   [4,5,6],
   [7,8,9]]

b=8.1
```

and I want to find the index of the value b in a, I can do:

```
nonzero(abs(a-b)<0.5)
```

to get (2,1) as the index, but what do I do if b is a 1d or 2d array?  Say,

```
b=[8.1,3.1,9.1]
```

and I want to get (2,1),(0,2),(2,2)

In general I expect only one match in a for every value of b.  Can I avoid a for loop?

Comment: Use a list comprehension on `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[nonzero(abs(x-a)<0.5) for x in b]
```

Comment: What if b is a 2d array?

Comment: Then use nested list comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

Vectorized approach with [`NumPy's broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
np.argwhere((np.abs(a - b[:,None,None])<0.5))[:,1:]
```

Explanation -

1. Extend `b` from a 1D to a 3D case with [`None/np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis), keeping the elements along the first axis.
2. Perform absolute subtractions with the 2D array `a`, thus bringing in broadcasting and leading to a 3D array of elementwise subtractions.
3. Compare against the threshold of `0.5` and get the indices corresponding to matches along the last two axes and sorted by the first axis with `np.argwhere(...)[:,1:]`.

Sample run -

```
In [71]: a
Out[71]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [72]: b
Out[72]: array([ 8.1,  3.1,  9.1,  0.7])

In [73]: np.argwhere((np.abs(a - b[:,None,None])<0.5))[:,1:]
Out[73]: 
array([[2, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [0, 0]])
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first entry of the output array be `[2,1]` instead of `[0,2]`?  Is there a way to prevent it from re-ordering the array?  I need:             `array([[2, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [2, 2]])`

Comment: @AB Check out the edits please. Edited accordingly assuming the order is important.